# Calling commandLine exe from C# application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, command-prompt

I have a commandline exe which accepts file path values and List of doubles as input and returns a List of doubles (out Variable) as output. These parameters are accepted based on option keys. Something like mentioned below,

```
C:\Test.exe  
Usage: Test.exe[options <arguments>..]

Options: 

-x filepathAInput   
-y filepathBInput  
-z DoubleListInput  
-o DoubleListOutput
```

I want to call this exe from my c# application and get the output results.
I tried using ProcessStartInfo, but passing multiple params is becoming tricky,

Which approach I should take?

Comment: What did you try? What problem did you have? `Process.Start` is exactly what you need.

Comment: You could look at using string interpolation to build up the arguments string.

Comment: You might want to add the code that you are doing that is starting to get tricky.

Comment: What kind of parameter is "DoubleListOutput" actually? How can an input parameter be output?